# Github Pages requesting wrong url when deploying react app

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

After publishing my react app, I noticed the page was blank, after going to the network tab on inspect, I realized Github pages was requesting:

/assets/index-1acd6362.js

instead of:

/project-name/assets/index-1acd6362.js

My package.json already has the correct url on the homepage field.

https://github.com/migars123/react-league-champs

https://migars123.github.io/react-league-champs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`homepage` in `package.json` is for `create-react-app`

For vite you need to set [`base`](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base) in vite config to your github repo name

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: '/react-league-champs/'
})
```